# convert geometry distance to geography distance in Postgresql

Tags: geometry, distance, postgis, postgresql-9.3, geography

I calculate geometry distance between point and polygon using st_distance. as the St_ExteriorRing works with geometry, I used geometry, but the problem is this distance id different with the distance in ArcGIS!
would you please let me know how I can get the geography distance!

```
  select ST_Distance(   
(select ST_ExteriorRing(geom) AS ering from osm_art_shops where gid =1),
(select geom from art_shops_flickr where id=5124.00000000)
);
```

result: 0.0341673143905709

but the distance in ArcGIS is: 2,787.07meters

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, that's possible by casting geometry to geography using ::geography.
this is the example

```
select ST_Distance( 
(SELECT ST_ExteriorRing(geom) AS ering from osm_art_shops where gid =1)::Geography,
(select geom from art_shops_flickr where id=5124.00000000)::Geography
);
```

distance: 2790.108402858 meters which is almost same as the distance calculated in ArcMap